# What does this voltmeter measure?

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

Consider the following circuit where i(t) is sinusoidal and exists across both components. (1) is an inductor and (2) is a capacitor. The ideal voltmeters measure effective value. What is the value measured by V2:

[image]

The correct answer should be 2V

My attempt. 
I know we can only apply KVL using phasors. The current phasor should be $$Ie^{j\theta}$$

The voltage across the inductor is $$\omega LIe^{j(\theta+\pi/2)}=V_1e^{j(\theta+\pi/2)}$$
The voltage across the capacitor is $$\frac{I}{\omega C}e^{j(\theta+-\pi/2)}=V_2e^{j(\theta-\pi/2)}$$

And the voltage across both components $$(\omega L-\frac{1}{\omega C})Ie^{j(\theta+-\pi/2)}=Ve^{j(\theta+\pi/2)}$$

And so applying KVL we get to

$$Ve^{j(\theta+\pi/2)}=V_1e^{j(\theta+\pi/2)}+V_2e^{j(\theta-\pi/2)}$$
$$Ve^{j\pi/2)}=V_1e^{j(\pi/2)}+V_2e^{j(-\pi/2)}$$

And dividing everything by $$\sqrt{2}$$

$$V_{eff}e^{j\pi/2)}=V_{1eff}e^{j(\pi/2)}+V_{2eff}e^{j(-\pi/2)}$$

Substituting by the known values

$$1e^{j\pi/2)}=1e^{j(\pi/2)}+V_{2eff}e^{j(-\pi/2)}$$ 
$$0=V_{2eff}e^{j(-\pi/2)}$$

And so $$V_{2eff}=0$$.

However the correct answer should be +2V.

Can someone help me to figure out my mistake? It's probably a conceptual mistake.

Comment: First mistake I see that wire connects on the circuit must be designated with dots in their connection points. Your current circuit, if formally looking at it, has no connections in the perpendicular joints, thus all voltmeters should show 0. And actually starting reading the text I do not see inductor and capacitor in the circuit diagram! Please take time making circuit right up to standards and common sense, and respect other people reading your posts and investing their time in helping you.

Comment: If the capacitor is infinite in value then V2 is zero but V1 would still equal V. But there is also a case where C can be finite and produce 2V and still give V1=V.

Comment: @Anonymous I ripped the image from the textbook I'm studying from. The image was that.

Comment: @Andyaka hi! thanks but can you elaborate a bit more, please? I'm still not convinced on how to do this mathematically

Comment: The basic problem is that you quote a question that asks for V2 but, without values for L and C you cannot possibly get a numerical answer nor a ratio - it depends entirely on the values of L and C and, by inference the excitation frequency. None of which is in your question. Then you say V2 = 2V (as an afterthought).

Comment: Why is there a phase shift of pi/2 over the whole thing? Shouldn't that be 0? (it's a long time I did something like this, so I could be complete off track)